# Searching Array of Objects with two search values

Tags: javascript, api

so I am trying to make an app that has two search criterias. The front-end app basically fetches data and you have two search bars to filter out the incoming data.

One search is by name and the other is by school name, the tricky part is that the either of the search also takes into account if there is some value in the other search parameter.

For example, if you search for "California University" and "Bob", you should get only Bobs that go to California University to render on the screen. But it seems like right now my DOM only renders the most recent search Ive made. What is the best way to go about a filter that filters both student name and school name using an event listener (keyup) on the search inputs?

```
searchByNameInput.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
const filterNameArray = studentArray.filter((student) => {
 // code here to filter students with this name and render it on DOM
}
}

searchBySchoolName.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
//filters students who go to this school and render it on DOM
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a single filtering function that checks both inputs, and call it from both event listeners.

```
function filterStudents() {
    const nameFilter = searchByNameInput.value;
    const schoolFilter = searchBySchoolName.value;
    const filterArray = studentArray.filter(student => 
        (nameFilter == '' || student.name.includes(nameFilter) &&
        (schoolFilter == '' || student.school.includes(schoolFilter))
}

searchByNameInput.addEventListener("keyup", filterStudents);
searchBySchoolNameInput.addEventListener("keyup", filterStudents);
```

Answer (score 0):

first filter your object and please try it include() method instead of filter().
as a above example
here filterData is my new filtered object and stu_data is my array.
get all search value from search input.
Example:-

```
     var filterData = stu_data.filter((stu_filter) => {
  return (stu_filter.firstname.toLowerCase().includes(filter) ||              
  stu_filter.lastname.toLowerCase().includes(filter))})
```

I hope this is help for you!
happy coding :)